# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'

Tags: python, numpy, google-geocoder

I am trying to convert the latitude and longitude to zipcodes for around 10k data points. I am using geocoder for the task.

```
lat = subsamp['Latitude'].as_matrix
long = subsamp['Longitude'].as_matrix

g = geocoder.google([lat, long], method='reverse')

zip = g.postal
```

But, on executing the geocoder I get the error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'

I tried running it using a Pandas series then Numpy array but does not work.

Comment: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is a built-in function, never do that, rename it to `zip_code` or something

Answer (score 9):

Its a Missing parentheses issue for `.as_matrix`,
**[pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html#pandas-dataframe-as-matrix), is a method**
used to convert the frame to its Numpy-array representation.

As it is a function, you missed the `()`, you have not added `()` function parenthesis, for `.as_matrix`.

```
lat = subsamp['Latitude'].as_matrix
long = subsamp['Longitude'].as_matrix
```

It should be as follows :

```
lat = subsamp['Latitude'].as_matrix()
long = subsamp['Longitude'].as_matrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

zip is a number or string but you have assigned a function to this value.
`zip = g.postal` -> `zip = g.postal()`