# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function' – Python/Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have the following code snippet from a program called Flights.py

```
...
#Load the Dataset
df = dataset
df.isnull().any()
df = df.fillna(lambda x: x.median())

# Define X and Y
X = df.iloc[:, 2:124].values
y = df.iloc[:, 136].values
X_tolist = X.tolist()

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

The second to last line is throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-d4add2ccf5ab>", line 3, in <module>
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)

  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 494, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 560, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)

  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 583, in partial_fit
    estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)

  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'
```

My dataframe `df` is of size (22587, 138)

I was taking a look at the following question for inspiration:

[TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method' in Geocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579753/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-method-in-geocod)

I tried the following adjustment:

```
# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train.as_matrix)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test.as_matrix)
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'
```

I'm currently at a loss for how to scan thru the dataframe and find/convert the offending entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269860/4909087) explains, `fillna` isn't designed to work with a callback. If you pass one, it will be taken as the literal fill value, meaning your `NaN`s will be replaced with lambdas:

```
df

      col1  col2  col3  col4
row1  65.0    24  47.0   NaN
row2  33.0    48   NaN  89.0
row3   NaN    34  67.0   NaN
row4  24.0    12  52.0  17.0

df4.fillna(lambda x: x.median())

                                    col1  col2  \
row1                                  65    24   
row2                                  33    48   
row3  <function <lambda> at 0x10bc47730>    34   
row4                                  24    12   

                                    col3                                col4  
row1                                  47  <function <lambda> at 0x10bc47730>  
row2  <function <lambda> at 0x10bc47730>                                  89  
row3                                  67  <function <lambda> at 0x10bc47730>  
row4                                  52                                  17
```

---

If you are trying to fill by median, the solution would be to create a dataframe of medians based on the column, and pass that to `fillna`.

```
df
      col1  col2  col3  col4
row1  65.0    24  47.0   NaN
row2  33.0    48   NaN  89.0
row3   NaN    34  67.0   NaN
row4  24.0    12  52.0  17.0

df.fillna(df.median())
df 
      col1  col2  col3  col4
row1  65.0    24  47.0  53.0
row2  33.0    48  52.0  89.0
row3  33.0    34  67.0  53.0
row4  24.0    12  52.0  17.0
```

Comment: If you pass a Series pandas can align them so you don't actually need transform or broadcasting. `df.fillna(df.median())`.

Comment: @ayhan I didn't know that! Thank you.

Comment: I used `df.fillna(df.median())` now I am getting the same error as earlier in the day, before I put in the lambda `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

Comment: @HMLDude it is possibly an issue with your data... you should look into using `df.clip`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html

Comment: So I just eyeballed the data and there are still a ton of rows with NaN values in `df `after calling `df.fillna(df.median())`.

Comment: @HMLDude Try: `med = pd.DataFrame(df.transform('median').values[:, None].T * np.ones_like(df), 
                   columns=df.columns, index=df.index);
df = df.fillna(med)`

Comment: I saw that as your initial answer. It results in the following error: `ValueError: transforms cannot produce aggregated results`.

Comment: @HMLDude If you would be so kind as to provide a snippet of the data that is producing the error, I could help debug. At this rate, I have no idea what the problem is nor can I begin to think of a solution for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154634/discussion-between-hmldude-and-cs).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.fillna(lambda x: x.median())
```

This is not really a valid way of using `fillna`. It expects literal values here, or a mapping from column to literal values. It will not apply the function you've provided; instead the value of NA cells will simply be set to the function itself. This is the function that your estimator is attempting to turn into a float.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same troubles using `df = df.fillna(lambda x: x.median())`
Here is my solution to get true values rather than 'function' into dataframe:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

I create dataframe 10 lines, 3 colunms with nan

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(10,3)))
df.iloc[3:5,0] = np.nan
df.iloc[4:6,1] = np.nan
df.iloc[5:8,2] = np.nan
```

Attribute stupid column labels for convenience afterward

```
df.columns=['Number_of_Holy_Hand_Grenades_of_Antioch', 'Number_of_knight_fleeings', 'Number_of_rabbits_of_Caerbannog']

print df.isnull().any()  # tell if nan per column
```

For each Column through their labels, we fill all the nan value by median value computed on the column itself. Can be used with mean(), etc.

```
for i in df.columns:     #df.columns[w:] if you have w column of line description 
    df[i] = df[i].fillna(df[i].median() )
print df.isnull().any()
```

Now df contains nan replaced by median value

```
print df
```

you can do for example

```
X = df.ix[:,:].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_std = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

which doesn't work with `df = df.fillna(lambda x: x.median())`
We can now use df into forward method because all values are true values, not function; contrary to method using lambda into dataframe.fillna() like e.g., [all proposals using fillna combined to lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns)