# IBM Data Science: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'

Tags: python, data-science

I'm trying to run the following code:

```py
#calculate the mean vaule for "stroke" column
avg_stroke=df['stroke'].astype('float').mean(axis=0)
print("Average of stroke:", avg_stroke)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'` on this code.
```

I have used the same code structure in different parts of my script and achieve a nice clean mean:

```py
#Write your code below and press Shift+Enter to execute 
avg_norm_loss = df["normalized-losses"].astype("float").mean(axis=0)
print("Average of normalized-losses:", avg_norm_loss)
```

I've already ruled out any suggestions/answers from these SE answers:

- [TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method' - Multiple variable regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664687/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-method-multipl)
- [TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579753/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-method)

Comment: Can you show us what is contained inside your data frames, from the examples above?

Comment: [Here is the CSV file] (https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DA0101EN/auto.csv)  + I added the headers <headers = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration", "num-of-doors","body-style",
         "drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base", "length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type",
         "num-of-cylinders", "engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower",
         "peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]> @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for ugly formatting, this is my first time posting lol. Thanks for your interest in helping out!

Comment: The csv file you provided did not contain the column named `stroke` it seems.

Comment: @GustavRasmussen, I added the headers in a later line of code (see my previous comment)

Comment: Ah, my bad, nevermind..

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that in that column a string with value "?" exists?
You have to remove it first. Other than that the code works for me.

```
import pandas as pd
url = r"https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DA0101EN/auto.csv"
col_names = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration", "num-of-doors","body-style", "drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base", "length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type", "num-of-cylinders", "engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower", "peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]
df = pd.read_csv(url, names=col_names)

df = df[df['stroke']!="?"]

avg_stroke = df['stroke'].astype('float').mean(axis=0)
print("Average of stroke:", avg_stroke)
#out: Average of stroke: 3.255422885572139
```

Comment: Yes - I am aware. I took care of that in an earlier line of code which I applied to the entire csv doc. I should have mentioned that. I am stunned that the code works for you. I might just be experiencing an anomaly (highly doubt it - user error is a b*tch). Thank you!

Comment: could you do me a favor, the moment the code crashes, can you execute print(df['stroke']) and also print(df['stroke'].unique()) ? and post the results?